# Dialog with blurry background at certain position

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, blur, layoutparams

I am trying to have a blurry background behind an AlertDialog. The process goes like the following: take a screenshot of the activity and blur it and save it to a bitmap. Then converting this bitmap to a drawable. Then I set the drawable background of the window of the alert using this line of code `renameDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(draw);` 
The issue is that the dialog is only getting shown on the top of the screen even though I am forcing a certain location by specifying a layout parameters. I noticed if I changed `setBackgroundDrawable` to `setBackgroundDrawableResource` and give it an existing drawable, then the dialog is shown at the specified location.

What needs to be done so that the `setBackgroundDrawable` can be used with a specified location to the dialog?

Thanks!

```
        AlertDialog renameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rename_playlist, null);

        //Getting Blurry screenshot to display it behind dialog
        Bitmap backgroundScreenshot = Utils.takeScreenShot(PlaylistActivity.this);
        Bitmap blurryBackground = Utils.getBlurredBitmap(backgroundScreenshot, 30);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = renameDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        wmlp.x= 100;
        wmlp.y= 100;


        final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blurryBackground);
        renameDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(draw);

        renameDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
        renameDialog.setView(deleteDialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        renameDialog.show();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting backround as a last action on the dialog?

Comment: Try this library : [Blur Dialog Fragment](https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment)

Comment: @wasyl yes i did, it didn't work. I believe the problem has to do with the style as well.

Comment: @vipul_asri Thanks, but I do not want to use a library for it.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the window's background to a screen-sized drawable, you're making the window grow to full-screen dimensions. In this case, `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` cannot do anything. Calculating with `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` works something like this:

```
spacingAtTop = spacingAtBottom = (containerHeight - contentHeight) / 2
```

After setting the background, `contentHeight` is equal to `containerHeight`.

If possible, post `R.layout.dialog_rename_playlist`.

One thing you can try without changing much:

Wrap the content of `R.layout.dialog_rename_playlist` inside a `FrameLayout` with height set to `match_parent`. The current parent(call it oldParent) of `R.layout.dialog_rename_playlist` should then have its height set to `wrap_content` and `layout_gravity` set to `center_vertical`. This should at least bring your content to the center. But it won't fix your positioning issue.

A more robust approach would be to use `FrameLayout` as the parent container for your `Activity/Fragment`. before displaying the dialog, take a screenshot, blur it, and set it to this `FrameLayout's` **foreground**. Make your `AlertDialog's` background transparent, and you should get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of guesses

```
wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL; //put me in the middle vertically
wmlp.x= 100; //sorry i have no effect
wmlp.y= 100;//dude!! you are wasting lines; i have no effect
```

do this

```
wmlp.gravity = Gravity.FILL; // i grow up when needed
wmlp.x= 100; // now i am useful
wmlp.y= 100; //dude!! you are wasting lines; use wmlp.y = wmlp.x = 100
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/PopupWindowCompat.html)